# Storing data in an array angular

Tags: angular

How do I check with the console to see if I'm actually storing the ids inside my domain array? If I try to put the console.log outside of the function nothing appears. I'm just not quite sure if I'm saving them or not.

What I would like to accomplish with this, is using that values of that array and passing them to my child component using @input decorator.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  ActivatedRoute,
  ParamMap
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Location
} from '@angular/common';
import {
  ImageService
} from './shared/image.service';
import {
  DomainService
} from '../domain.service';
import {
  GraphService
} from '../graph.service';
import {
  LibraryService
} from '../library.service';
import {
  Domain
} from '../library';
import {
  Library
} from '../library';
import {
  map,
  mergeMap
} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-metric-details',
  templateUrl: './metric-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./metric-details.component.css']
})
export class MetricDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  visibleImages: any[] = [];
  activeId = 0;
  domain: Domain[];

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService, private domainService: DomainService, private libraryService: LibraryService, private graphService: GraphService, private location: Location, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        {
          this.activeId = +params['id'];
          console.log(this.activeId) //log the entire params object
          // console.log(params['id']) //log the value of id
          // const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
          // console.log(id);
          console.log(this.domainService.getDomain(this.activeId));
          this.domainService.getDomain(this.activeId).subscribe(domain => this.domain = domain)
          console.log("YOOO", this.domain)

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: you are doing it right,  it's an async call that's why your log shows nothing.

Comment: @Vikas Ok I think I understand, so there is no way I could see it?

Comment: yes you can move the console.log inside subscribe. `subscribe(domain => {this.domain = domain; console.log(this.domain);})`

Comment: Yeah looks like I've always been doing it. Thank you.

Comment: Another quick question I have, since I'm storing the values in domain:Domain[], if I wanted to shouldn't I be able to transfer the array to a child component by using the child's selector inside my parents html file like so "<!-- <app-metric-view [domain] = "domain"></app-metric-view> -->" then using the decorator @input to get that array and use it how I please? I would setup the decorator like this in my child's component like so @Input() domain: Domain[]; Then I should be able to use domain.id if I wanted inside a function in my child's class?

Comment: since it's an async call you can conditionally load the component using `*ngIf="domain"`

Comment: Wouldn't that only be in the component it was defined? Say the parent component. I wouldnt be able to do that in the child's component. If i didnt pass the array to it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168424/discussion-between-vikas-and-pennyboy).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are missing some tokens:

```js
      import {
      Component,
      OnInit,
      Input
    } from '@angular/core';

    import {
      Router,
      ActivatedRoute,
      ParamMap
    } from '@angular/router';

    import {
      Location
    } from '@angular/common';

    import {
      ImageService
    } from './shared/image.service';

    import {
      DomainService
    } from '../domain.service';

    import {
      GraphService
    } from '../graph.service';

    import {
      LibraryService
    } from '../library.service';

    import {
      Domain
    } from '../library';

    import {
      Library
    } from '../library';

    import {
      map,
      mergeMap
    } from 'rxjs/operators';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-metric-details',
      templateUrl: './metric-details.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./metric-details.component.css']
    })
    export class MetricDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

      visibleImages: any[] = [];
      activeId = 0;
      domain: Domain[];

      constructor(private imageService: ImageService, private domainService: 
DomainService,
        private libraryService: LibraryService, private graphService: 
GraphService,
        private location: Location, private route: ActivatedRoute, private 
router: Router) {
        this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            {
              this.activeId = +params['id'];
              console.log(this.activeId); // log the entire params object
              // console.log(params['id']) //log the value of id
              // const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
              // console.log(id);
              console.log(this.domainService.getDomain(this.activeId));
              this.domainService.getDomain(this.activeId).subscribe(domain => this.domain = domain);
              console.log('YOOO', this.domain);

            }
          });
        }}
```